# Can I deduct "Non-Reimbursable Expenses"?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

I have this item in my pay stubs:

```
Non-Reimbursable Expenses
```

I wonder if I can deduct it. My employer told me that it is for 'legal and accounting expenses'. My W-2 makes no mention of it. The total for the year is more than 2% of AGI.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it something you spent at the employer's request?

Comment: @littleadv No, I didn't spend it. They just take it.

Comment: Who? What do you mean "just take it"?

Comment: @littleadv My employer. I mean this item takes money from every pay stub I get, without me spending anything.

Comment: for what purpose? It doesn't make sense... Employer just taxes money from your after tax pay without your permission?

Comment: @littleadv purpose of 'legal and accounting expenses'. I know..., but what goes into my pocket is what was agreed, so no biggie on that. Just wondering if I can deduct the item...

Comment: It appears to me, from what you've described, that your employer is using you to reduce his tax bill. There's no expense here. Just shifting of tax burden from your employer, who pays you pre-tax larger amounts on which you pay tax, and then takes the difference after tax. I think the legal term would be *stealing* and *money laundering*. I suggest you consider discussing this with an attorney and start looking for another job.

Comment: And no, you cannot deduct something you didn't spend.

Comment: @littleadv Thanks! Please use your last line as an answer so it'll be one of the options. I'll give this question some time in case others want to discuss.

Comment: "... but what goes into my pocket is what was agreed, so no biggie on that." If you got your 2013 W-2 already, **read** the numbers in Boxes 1, 3, and 5 to see what the employer is reporting as your wages. If these amounts include the money deducted as legal and accounting expenses, then it is indeed a biggie because you have to pay income tax on the amount in Box 1, and you have already paid Social Security tax and Medicare tax on the amounts in Boxes 3 and 5 respectively.

Comment: @DilipSarwate good point. I never calculated the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only deduct (with the 2% AGI threshold) expenses that:

1. You've actually incurred. I.e.: you actually paid for equipment or services provided and can show receipts for the payment.
2. At the request of the employer. I.e.: you didn't just decide on your own to buy a new book or take a class, your employer **told** you to.
3. With business necessity. I.e.: it was in order for you to do your job.
4. And you were not reimbursed by your employer.

I.e.: you went somewhere and spent your after tax money on something employer explicitly told you to pay for, and you didn't get reimbursed for that.

From your story - these conditions don't hold for you.

As I said in the comments - I strongly suggest you talk to a lawyer. Your story just doesn't make any sense, and I suspect your employer is doing something very fishy here.